# python Image not getting loaded

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

The image is not getting loaded though I gave the path correctly.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
a = Image.open('me.jpg')
a.show()
```

I am using OpenCV2.4 on Windows 8 64bit.

Comment: You gave the path correctly? There is no path in your code, just the file name.

Answer (score 0):

If your sure the picture is at the project dir try:

At your code there is no path, only file name....

```
import cv2
import os
from PIL import Image

a = Image.open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/me.jpg')
a.show()
```